# removing all trailing slashes in an url

Tags: php, regex

I have written a `preg_match` code to remove all trailing slashes and that is as follows..

```
preg_replace("/(\/?)+$/",'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

will this hold good any time.

what is the alternatives to remove all trailing slashes...

consider that the users would give sitename.com/folder/ or sitename.com/folder// or sitename.com/folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
$path = rtrim($path','/');
```

Comment: I was thinking that rtrim will remove only one occurrence. It worked. haha i was thinking too much. as ususal.

Answer (score 0):

```
See bellow:

<?php
$url = "http://example.co/4569128/removing-all-trailing-slashes-in-an-url/" 

$newUrl = rtrim($url','/'); 

?>
Output : http://example.co/4569128/removing-all-trailing-slashes-in-an-url

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```